# Hide a DIV after 5 seconds or when the user clicks the close link

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout

For reference, please see the jsFiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WillCode4Cash/xSRk8/2/).  Here's a short script that displays a stackoverflow-style popup message.  What I want to do is give the user the option of either letting the message go away on it's own after 5 seconds or to dismiss the message by clicking the 'X' on the right side of the message dialog.

I've tried to add a delay:

```
$("#message").fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).queue(function() {
    $('#message').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Which will work, but then the onClick event on the 'X' link to close the message dialog won't fire.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clicking the 'X' works fine...you have to make sure you're not clicking on 'Result` in the fiddle corner, then it wont fire.

Comment: @tymeJV Correct, it does work, but when I add the delay to fadeOut the DIV after 5 seconds, the onClick no longer works. I would like to have both - meaning, if the user doesn't close the dialog after 5 seconds, then it will close itself.

Comment: I changed your CSS styling for #message to `top:80` to get it off of the `Result` indicator.

Comment: Note that you don't need `.queue()`, you can just say `$("#message").fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#message").fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');

$('#message a.close-notify').click(function () {
    $('#message').stop().fadeOut('slow', removeMessageLayer);
    $('#messageContainer').text();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xSRk8/15/

The reason why clicking the X to close stopped working when you added the automatic fade is that jQuery queues up animation methods, so in your click handler where you tried to `fadeOut()` the element that fade out was added to the queue *after* the delay. If you call [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) it cancels any existing queued effects so you can do the `fadeOut()` immediately.

Also your `removeMessageLayer()` function wasn't actually removing the message element at all - you just thought it was gone because it had faded out. Your code

```
$('body').remove('#message');
```

...says to remove the body element if it matches the selector passed to `remove()`, which of course it never would. You need `$('#message').remove();`, and you don't need to test whether the message element exists first because jQuery essentially ignores the `.remove()` if called on an empty jQuery object. So use this:

```
function removeMessageLayer() {
    $('#message').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(body).on('click','#message a.close-notify',function () {
    $('#message').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#messageContainer').text();
    removeMessageLayer();
    return false;
});
```

because it is a dynamically created element, best practice says the click event should be delegated.

```
    $("#message").fadeIn('slow',function() {
        $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

This will give you your five second delay based on the successful creation of the message.

Comment: A delegated handler may be more sensible, but you don't _need_ one in this case because the OP's code only called `.click()` _after_ creating the element in question.

Comment: I'm simply trying to promote `best practice` while answering questions. You're right, it's not NECESSARY but it is preferred and I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Note that if using a delegated handler like that, that code should be moved out of the `displayMessage()` function, otherwise it'll bind additional handlers every time a message is displayed.

Comment: Would you be happier if I just deleted my answer?

Comment: Sorry. No, I think a delegated handler is a fine alternative here.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the cleanest, but you could add a `setTimeout` call at the end of your `displayMessage` function.

```
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#message').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#messageContainer').text();
        removeMessageLayer();
        return false;
    }, 5000);
```

And then in your click handler, call `clearTimeout(timeout)` to cancel the timeout.

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSRk8/9/) with this.  Seems to work.

**UPDATE**: the code isn't clean -- I repeated some things.  But I'll leave the clean up as a future exercise.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The code will be  (tested )

```
$("#message").fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow'); // display message div
$('#message-close').click(function () {   // click close button
$('#message').stop().fadeOut('slow');

 return false;
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

if (e.keyCode === 27) {
   $('#message').stop().fadeOut('slow'); // close div when Esc key is pressed
      }
  });
});
```